# How to replace NaN values where the other columns meet a certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I am working on the titanic datset from Kaggle and am trying to replace the NaN values in one column based on information from the other columns.

In my specific example I am trying to replace the unknown age of male, 1st class passengers with the average age of male, 1st class passengers.

How do I do this?

I have been able to segment the data and replace the null values of that new dataframe, but it doesn't carry over to the original dataframe and I am a bit unclear on how to make it do so.

Here is my code:

```
missingage_1stclass_male = pd.DataFrame(
    titanic[
        (titanic['Age'].isnull()) &
        (titanic['Pclass'] == 1) &
        (titanic['Sex'] == 'male')
    ]
)
missingage_1stclass_male.Age.fillna(40.5, inplace=True)
```

My original dataframe with all the values is named titanic.

Comment: look at `np.select` should solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to replace the unknown age of male, 1st class passengers
>   with the average age of male, 1st class passengers.

You can split the problem into 2 steps. First calculate the average age of male, 1st class passengers:

```
mask = (df['Pclass'] == 1) & (df['Sex'] == 'male')
avg_filler = df.loc[mask, 'Age'].mean()
```

Then update values satisfying your criteria:

```
df.loc[df['Age'].isnull() & mask, 'Age'] = avg_filler
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. And it works! Thank you for a clear and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can group the data by required columns and fillna, something like

```
df['age'] = df.groupby(['pclass', 'sex']).age.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Edit: for filling null values of only specific rows

```
df.loc[((df.pclass == 1) & (df.sex == 'male') & (df.age.isnull())) , 'age'] = df.loc[((df.pclass == 1) & (df.sex == 'male') ) , 'age'].mean()
```

Comment: Why did you include .age ?

Comment: That is because we are trying to fillna only for age column. Another way of writing the same would be df.groupby(['pclass', 'sex']).apply(lambda x: x.age.fillna(x.mean()))

Comment: Okay, thank you. This is helpful but when I run it it fills the null values for all of the age data. I am wondering how to fill the age data WHEN the pclass is 1 and sex = male.

Comment: And do you want to fillna with the mean of the entire age column or the means of only rows corresponding pclass 1 and sex male?

Comment: The latter, the mean of the age of males in pclass = 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the .fillna() will help you with this

here is an example on how to use:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
...                    [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
...                    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
...                    [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
...                    columns=list('ABCD'))
>>> df
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4

>>> df.fillna(0)
A   B   C   D
0   0.0 2.0 0.0 0
1   3.0 4.0 0.0 1
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 5
3   0.0 3.0 0.0 4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! The issue is that I do not want to fill the the nullvalue with the same value. Fillna() used by itself only fills one value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the rows whose columns meet certain criteria and then replace it as your need.

```
df[df['Pclass'] == 1 & df['Sex'] == 'male'].fillna(df['age'].mean())
```

Comment: Hmm. I have tried this and it doesn't work: titanic[(titanic['Pclass'] == 1) & (titanic['Sex'] == 'male')].fillna(40.5, inplace=True)